# Array of generic nodes Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am implementing a concurrent circular Queue in terms of an array that makes use of separate locks
at the head and the tail of the queue. Each node in the queue looks as follows:

```
  private class Node<T> 
  {
        public T item;
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Node(){}
        void lock() {lock.lock();}
        void unlock() {lock.unlock();}
  }
```

I cannot create the queue in the constructor of the queue class.

```
public Queue(int capacity) {
    items = (Node[]) new Object[capacity];//This line gives the problem
    head = size = 0;
  }
```

I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047123/workaround-for-generic-arrays-in-java), but this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<T>[] slots = (Node<T>[]) new Node<?>[capacity];
```

Gives the following compiler error:

```
Cannot create a generic array of Queue<T>.Node<?>
```

My question is what is the correct way to initialize an array of generic objects?

Comment: maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to: generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation), see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Node<T>` should be static.

```
private static class Node<T> 
{
    public T item;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void lock() {lock.lock();}
    void unlock() {lock.unlock();}
}

...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Node<T>[] slots = (Node<T>[]) new Node<?>[capacity];
```

Generally we have two options:

**nonstatic class**

```
public class Queue2<T> {

    public Queue2(int capacity) {   

        Queue2<T>.Node2[] slots2 =  new Queue2.Node2[capacity];     
    }


    private class Node2 
    {
        private T item;
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public Node2(Object object) {}
        void lock() {lock.lock();}
        void unlock() {lock.unlock();}
    }
}
```

**static class**

```
public class Queue<T>  {

    public Queue(int capacity) {

        Queue.Node<T>[] slots = (Node<T>[]) new Node<?>[capacity];
    }   

    private static class Node<T> 
    {
        public T item;
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        void lock() {lock.lock();}
        void unlock() {lock.unlock();}
    }
}
```

You would refer to the node class in the first example as `Queue2<T>.Node`, whereas you would refer to the node class in the second example as `Queue.Node<T>`.

> Of the two alternatives showed here, the second is preferable. Nested classes that are not
>   static are implemented by including a reference to the enclosing instance, since they may, in general, access components of that instance. Static nested classes are usually both simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways to make this compile.

1. Make `Node` a public class
2. Keep `Node` as a private, non-static, class and remove the wildcard from the instantiation:

   `Node<T>[] slots = (Node<T>[]) new Node[capacity];`