# Java Array of Generic Nodes in a Binary Tree, can't create nil node

Tags: java, arrays, static, nodes, non-static

I'm having a similar problem as in this question:
[Array of generic nodes Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478225/array-of-generic-nodes-java)

However, making the nested Node class static solves the one problem but creates another for me. I've written a Binary Tree, and each time a Node's pointer isn't supposed to point to anything (e.g. a leaf node's left and right pointers, or the root's parent pointer), it actually points to a special "nil" node, which contains no relevant data. Nil is a member variable of the Binary Tree.

When I create a node, the constructor makes all pointers point to nil. However, if I make the Node class static so I can create an array of nodes (which I need to do for a particular method), I get an error for each pointer that says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field nil." But if I change nil to be static, I get an error for it which says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T." (My nodes hold parameterized type objects.)

Here's my Node class:

```
protected static class Node<T>{
    Node left, right, parent;
    T object;

    protected Node(T x) {
        object= x;
        left= nil;
        right= nil;
        parent= nil;
    }
}
```

This is the nil designation and the Binary Tree constructor, which creates the nil node and makes it the root:

```
protected static Node<T> nil;

public BT() {
    nil= new Node<T>(null);
    root= nil;
}
```

How do I allow myself to create an array of nodes without running into these static vs non-static issues?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't simply using `null` when a pointer isn't supposed to point to anything? Also, the `left`, `right` and `parent` fields should probably be of type `Node<T>` rather than the raw type `Node`.

Comment: Why is the nil *field* static? Yes, the class may need to be static, but that does not mean that the field `nil` does too.

Comment: I'm following a textbook in an online course (Open Data Structures by Pat Morin). Sometimes this guy has some really convoluted code, so it wouldn't surprise me if the nil node is unnecessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Because `nil` is referenced from a static context (in the static nested `Node` constructor).

Comment: @Andreas: then that is some crazy code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree, but if you want to write code without using `null` values, then that's how. See e.g. [Are null references really a bad thing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12777/202153) I personally disagree. Replacing `null` with `nil` doesn't really make the code less error-prone when only used inside the implementation of class. Eliminating `null` from the API, by e.g. using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

First, never use *raw* generics, so specify `<T>` on the `Node` fields:

```
protected static class Node<T> {
    Node<T> left, right, parent;
    T object;
```

Next, to initialize `nil`, you need a difference constructor:

```
protected Node() {
    left = this;
    right = this;
    parent = this;
}
```

Now you can initialize `nil` as a non-static object, to keep type-safety:

```
protected Node<T> nil = new Node<>();
```

Though, rather than creating a `nil` object for every tree, create a static method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static Node NIL = new Node();

@SuppressWarnings({ "cast", "unchecked" })
protected static <T> Node<T> nil() {
    return (Node<T>) NIL;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed my mistake with the raw generics. I had been adding and deleting so much to try to make things work, I missed it when I posted here.

Comment: This works for creating the nil node, but when using the other constructor to create the other nodes, I still can't point to the nil node for the reasons stated above. Your suggestion is to point them to themselves, but then I have to change my implementation in all my methods to fix the pointers after I create a new node. Is this what I need to do? Will this even work if I point to the nil node after the new node has been constructed?